# Setting up a secondary Vim environment

Tags: vim, vimrc

I've  setup the [YADR dotfile repo](https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles) on one of my machines, and find it very powerful/useful. Though it's definitely slower than my present Vim setup with all its plugins, I'd still like to be able to use it for larger projects, and use my own simpler setup for quicker edits. Is there a way I that I could install YADR as a separate Vim environment to be invoked with an alias?

---

I understand how a lot of Vim users feel about these large dotfile repos. This just gives me a chance to experiment with YADR's features and to take and leave what I want from it, so that I can eventually be left with a better custom environment.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing that is sourced when Vim starts up is its `~/.vimrc`; after that, plugins are loaded according to the `'runtimepath'` option.

Therefore, to use a separate Vim environment, you just need to pass in a different `.vimrc` location (via `-u /path/to/vimrc`), and in there modify the `'runtimepath'` accordingly (i.e. away from the default `~/.vim/` directory tree). The `:help -u` even explicitly mentions this:

> This can be used to start Vim in a special mode, with special mappings and settings.  A shell alias can be used to make this easy to use.